# React Vite dev server on subpath produces 404

Tags: reactjs, vite

I am setting up a project with vite and react inside a docker container behind a reverse proxy.

When it runs at the root of the domain everything works great.

When I push the app in a subpath the actual document works fine but the on the vite resources I get 404 errors on

```bash
https://server.test/path1  [200 OK]

# The rest are 404
https://server.test/path1/node_modules/.vite/deps/react_jsx-dev-runtime.js?v=7d105868
https://server.test/path1/node_modules/.vite/deps/react.js?v=7d105868
https://server.test/path1/src/index.css
https://server.test/path1/vite.svg
```

with vite config

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'
import tsconfigPaths from 'vite-tsconfig-paths'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  // This works great
  // base: 'https://server.test',
  // With the subpath I get 404 errors
  base: 'https://server.test/path1',
  server: {
    host: '0.0.0.0',
  },
  plugins: [react(), tsconfigPaths()],
})
```